# How to convert an Array of Array containing Integer to a Scala Spark List/Seq?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Scala spark. I have a string of array-like `"[[1,2,100], [1, 2, 111]]"` I don't how to convert that in Scala List or Sequence. I could not found a solution to it.

I tried to use circe parse method but it did not help me out.

```
val e = parse(json_string).getOrElse(Json.Null)

e.asArray.foreach(l => {
  println(l)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```scala
val r = "\\[(:?\\d+,? *)+\\]".r
r.findAllMatchIn(s).map { m => 
  val s = m.toString
  s.substring(1, s.length - 1).split(", *").map(_.toInt) 
}.toArray
```

For your example, it produces:
`res26: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(1, 2, 100), Array(1, 2, 111))`

Not sure what you want to do with the result after extracting it

Comment: It worked! I am gonna use this in spark UDF and apply some checks to return value.